# How to add different value with the same node name in Firebase realtime-database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I doing a project which require to receive the data from realtime database when user inserted the tracking id.

Here is my database.
[image]

In order to let the program search the data with the inserted tracking id, I need to add the tracking id into the reference node so that the program can query the data in the reference.

Here is how I add the data into the database for the tracking id.

```js
 private void addDetails() {
        String trackingid = enterTrackningID.getText().toString().trim();
        String latitude = enterLatitude.getText().toString().trim();
        String longitude = enterLongitude.getText().toString().trim();
        item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        NewTrackingID = String.valueOf(trackingid);
        NewLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
        NewLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
        Newitem = String.valueOf(item);

        Toast.makeText(this, "New Tracking ID = " + NewTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "New Latitude = " + NewLatitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,"New Longitude = "+ NewLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status of parcel" + Newitem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        rootNode =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("HostID");

        TrackingIDClass IDclass = new TrackingIDClass(NewLatitude, NewLongitude, NewTrackingID, Newitem);
        StatusClass statusClass = new StatusClass(Newitem);


        reference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("TrackingID").child(NewTrackingID).setValue(IDclass);

        HashMap <String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updates.put("ID",NewTrackingID);

        reference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Reference").updateChildren(updates);


        Intent i = new Intent(AddTrackingIDtoDatabase.this, AddTrackingID.class);
        startActivity(i);

        finish();

    }
```

However, the program can only update the id value in the reference node only. I want to add the id of "111ww" into the id node so that the user can search the data in the reference node. Guys, what should I do in order to add the "111ww" into the reference node without losing the original id of "xxx" ?
Or is there has another way to send the data into the reference with the same node name of id?

Comment: What do you mean by "without losing the original id of "xxx""? As I see, you are using updateChildren() method, doesn't update the element as expected?

Comment: I mean I would like to add the id in trackingID node into the reference node. However, when I put the trackingID of xxx into the reference node, the id in reference node will be overwrite/updated and change from 111ww to xxx. Is that can be done in firebase to add the both tracking id into the node with the same child name in order to let the program query in the same child with different value?